# Efeito de botão pressionado

Tags: java, android

Tenho vários botões em uma aplicação e queria que eles tivessem o mesmo efeito do `Button` quando pressionado, pelo fato de serem vários botões, gostaria de criar um código em JAVA para isso e não pelo método de *States* no XML, pois teria que criar dezenas de *sprites* diferentes. Vi algo sobre utilizar `setOnTouchListener` com o `setColorFilter`, alguma luz?

Comment: setbackground não resolve?

Comment: Qual seria o efeito? Tem como descrever melhor?

Comment: <Button android:text="Botão"
             android:backgroung="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

Isso funciona. 

Acredito que se fizer o mesmo, via código java, vá funcionar. 
Não estou em condição de testar agora mas deve funcionar sim.

Comment: Exatamente, descobri um pouco antes de você comentar aqui, mas mesmo assim, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei o que queria, seria o `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` ou como o colega a cima falou `attr/selectableItemBackground`, basta colocar no *background* do *ImageButton*.